# How to specify a logback filter without overriding default logging pattern

Tags: logback, spring-logback

This logback.xml filter is not working. The Filter is not getting invoked at all.

```
<configuration>
    <include resource="org/springframework/boot/logging/logback/defaults.xml"/>
    <include resource="org/springframework/boot/logging/logback/console-appender.xml" />
    <filter class="com.myproject.config.RedactFilter" />
    <root level="INFO">
        <appender-ref ref="CONSOLE" />
    </root>
</configuration>
```

The filter does get invoked if I do this:

```
<configuration>
    <include resource="org/springframework/boot/logging/logback/defaults.xml"/>
    <include resource="org/springframework/boot/logging/logback/console-appender.xml" />
    <appender name="CONSOLE" class="ch.qos.logback.core.ConsoleAppender">
        <filter class="com.myproject.config.RedactFilter" />
        <encoder>
            <pattern>
                %-4relative [%thread] %-5level %logger -%kvp -%msg%n
            </pattern>
        </encoder>
    </appender>
    <root level="INFO">
        <appender-ref ref="CONSOLE" />
    </root>
</configuration>
```

However, I need to retain the default springboot logging pattern. If I remove the `<encoder>` or `<pattern>` element, I get the error:

```
Logging system failed to initialize using configuration from 'null'
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Logback configuration error detected: 
ERROR in ch.qos.logback.core.ConsoleAppender[CONSOLE] - No encoder set for the appender named "CONSOLE".
```

Is it possible to have a filter, but retain the default logging encoder?

Answer (score 0):

Try changing your structure to:

```
<configuration>
    <include resource="org/springframework/boot/logging/logback/defaults.xml"/>
    <include resource="org/springframework/boot/logging/logback/console-appender.xml" />
    <appender name="CONSOLE" class="ch.qos.logback.core.ConsoleAppender">
        <encoder>
            <pattern>
               ${CONSOLE_LOG_PATTERN}
            </pattern>
        </encoder>
        <filter class="com.myproject.config.RedactFilter" />
    </appender>
    <root level="INFO">
        <appender-ref ref="CONSOLE" />
    </root>
</configuration>
```

This should utilize your filter while still using the default spring-boot logger from https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/blob/fbe614a61bb55bf1f0ca917600494438e5551a02/spring-boot-project/spring-boot/src/main/java/org/springframework/boot/logging/logback/DefaultLogbackConfiguration.java#L70